# program fails to acquire args in main function

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, command

Please keep in mind first off that English is my second language. Therefore firstly I apologize for grammar/just sounding foolish. However it is my junior year in cs. and my professor has given us an assignment that i am suffering to understand the first portion of it. Let me start by posting where I am hung up on:

Write a program (in C) calledassignment4.ctargeted at the Linux platform that performs like a shell pipeline.Example:

## ./assignment4 ls : sort = # ls | sort

Where the colon breaks argv into a left (ls) and right (sort) portion.  Implementation will fork/exec and setup a pipesuch that:

parent:  left portion, runs with stdout = pipe write end

child:  right portion, runs with stdin = pipe read end•Consider swapping parent and child functions, why?

Where:  and  are optional parameters that specify the programsto be run.

**okay so that is just to provide some background information. I am at the part in my program where I am attempting to program my main function to be able to accept those 2 args. and simply print them back to me at this point. here is my MRE: (please keep in mind this is an MRE).

```
//################  #-for include
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
//################


int main(int b, char** locations) {

int ok = 0;
while (locations[ok] != NULL) {
printf("%s \n", locations[ok]);
ok++;
} printf("%s \n", locations[1]);

char * working = "/bin/ls"; // command!
//printf("%s \n", working);
char * arg1 = ""; // ls args
char * arg2 = "/home/yev/Desktop/lab 3"; // directory

//execlp( working, arg1, arg2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Where I am currently stuck on is the part of sort = # ls | sort.
whenever i try ./A3 sort = # ls | sort the console seems to attempt to run the sort command? defeating the point of me even trying to acquire the argument `"sort = # ls | sort"` because it wont output that string of text back to me either.

please help. once again it is difficult for me to understand sometimes, is this even a legit command? as  simply running: `"sort = # ls | sort"` in console gives the error: `"sort: cannot read: '=': No such file or directory"`

is this just a miss-understanding on my end? or is there a reason why the command wont work or why my mini script cant capture the line and print it back out to me? could the professor have meant something different? or is it operator error on my end?

Comment: Use quotes `"..."`

Comment: use quotes for the "blank blank blank"? and that will work for it?

Comment: it seems to me like that violates the write-up instructions

Comment: I haven't finished reading you question , however, you error appears to be because the shell is not sending your arguments to the program as they happen to be shell operators. In such a case, enclosing the arguments within `"..."` is the right thing to do. I may be wrong about the source of your errors, of course.

Comment: @itsMe "*violates wirte-up instructions*" , **no, but you *will* violate shell rules by sending `ls : sort = # ls | sort` without any quotes.**

Comment: okay it appears you have been correct! but because i always take things literally all the professor meant in that string of commands was that ls : sort, was logically equivelant to ls | sort.

Comment: can you proceed to write that as an answer? so that i may select that as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have several misunderstandings, not just one:

First, you should have received, and printed correctly the arguments to your program, as you do in the first part of your code:

```
    int ok = 0;
    while (locations[ok] != NULL) {
        printf("%s \n", locations[ok]);
        ok++;
    }
    printf("%s \n", locations[1]); /* danger here!! */
```

This piece of code will print all your program command line arguments, including the name of your program `locations[0]`, in the first line, one per line.  Then your print your first argument (without checking if it is `NULL` if you call your program without any argument, be carefull with this)

In the second part you have a complete mess.  First you need to know what is an argument for `ls` in the manual page.  Then you need to understand the parameters to `execlp(2)`.  The first argument to `execlp(2)` is the program you want to execute (`/bin/ls`, although you don't need to use the program name's path, because `execlp` already looks in the `PATH` environment variable for the directories to find the `ls` command in)  The second, third, etc. are the arguments to the program, but ***including again the argument `0`***, this is `ls` again. And you have to put a `NULL` at the end.  You have passed `""` as `argv[0]`, so `ls` will not know how it was called, and it will mess the error message, which should start with it's name.  The argument to `ls` will be `"/home/yev/Desktop/lab 3"`  So you need to have a directory/file called `/home/yev/Desktop/lab 3` in your system, or `ls` will complain with the message:

```
: /home/yev/Desktop/lab 3: No such file or directory.
```

(normally `ls` should write

```
ls: /home/yev/Desktop/lab 3: No such file or directory.
```

but as you have passed `""` as the program name, it uses that empty string to announce itself)

Your call should be:

```
    execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", "/home/yev/Desktop/lab 3", NULL);
```

And you must ensure your file is called `lab 3` (with a space), because the shell `sh` is not here to separate again the strings on the spaces in there.

More on, in your assignment you are not told at any moment that you have to process your program command line parameters, You need to create parameter lists for the commands `sort` and `ls` (it doesn't specify what parameters, if any, should be included, but in my opinion you have enough practice building the pipeline, which is what you have been asked to do)  As you don't include any question on this subject, theres's nothing to answer in this thing.